# Win 2008 - Stream Video To Multiple Monitors?

Tags: streaming, video, video-streaming, video-hosting

My question seems to be pretty simply presented but I'm in need of some help.  I've got a Win 2008 R2 server and 5 monitors stationed throughout an office.  These are just NEC Monitors with VGA/DVI (they may have hdmi but I'm not sure) inputs; definitely nothing fancy so DLNA is not an option (although I wish it was!)

I do NOT have a ton of AV knowledge and am trying to learn quickly.

I have attempted to use Ethernet to DVI Baluns to achieve the desired result.  I can get 2 remote monitors to use a 'combined desktop' and display video in fullscreen with a surprisingly good result.  I don't think windows will 'combine desktop' on more than 2 monitors however, and I need to have all 5 monitors displaying the same video.

The video playing will range from simple powerpoint presentations to active video of triathlons.

I have tried UltraMon with little success - the mirroring of displays just doesn't work fluidly enough to provide a good picture on high action videos.  Client/Server solutions such as MaxiVista are out as well because the monitors I want to stream the video to are just dumb monitors - no PC attached.

Any ideas, suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're looking to have the same thing displayed on all 5 monitors, correct?

Comment: Correct.  I would like to have all 5 monitors displaying the same content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't do product recommendations. But what you are looking for is called a *Video splitter* which would replicate a single input signal to a number of output signals. An example would be the [Aten VS-1208T](http://www.aten-usa.com/products/productItem.php?model_no=VS1208T) for VGA input/output or the [VS-0108H](http://www.aten-usa.com/products/productItem.php?model_no=VS0108H) for HDMI signals. A whole number of manufacturers produce this kind of devices, but you probably are facing some trial-and-error to get satisfactory results as the signal quality and the feature sets will vary massively.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I am looking for.  Would I be able to use just a generic ethernet to dvi adapter (like a ethernet to dvi balus I currently have) and plug in the monitors to that first switch you mentioned (for VGA)?  It seems that would be the case, and if it is - that is exactly what I am after!  Again, not going to be showing anything crazy on this, pretty basic setup.

Comment: Most likely you would need to use the baluns which are listed as "compatible" by the manufacturer - you might be lucky with a third party model, but cannot assume compatibility as there is no standardization for baluns. Aten has the [VE170 receiver baluns](http://www.aten-usa.com/products/productItem.php?model_no=VE170) which are meant to be used with the VS-1208T.

Comment: Yea, I saw that after I had posted my previous post.  I think you're right and I think this will be pretty much my only option at this point.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.  Either get a cheap itx or embedded pc for each monitor so that you can stream content across a network or get a multiway DVI/HDMI AV splitter.  HDMI and DVI are pin compatible so to use an HDMI one with your monitors you just need need a small socket adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest one the following :

1. AMD graphich card(5450 which is pretty cheap http://www.amd.com/US/PRODUCTS/TECHNOLOGIES/AMD-EYEFINITY-TECHNOLOGY/HOW-TO/Pages/faqs.aspx ) so you will have a fluid experience even at videos (depending on player and codecs , for power point it will make no difference )
2. Combine one AMD card with 1 kvm switches (4 kvm switch for 4 monitors ) - 2 real connections (one on hdmi to DVI , and one DVI-DVI).Examples of KVM switches: http://aten-usa.com/?product&cat=787&Item=CS1644 .

Comment: These monitors are simply too far to be connecting them directly via DVI.  The idea is to stream over the network and have it go specifically to these monitors.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have 2 ways:

- Output stream through server video card. Then you should go with ATI eyefinity card that can handle up to 6 monitors. I don't understand why you combine monitors, you just need to launch 5 powerpoint (one per screen). Will much depend on distance between server & screen
- Use devices that have one ethernet and one monitor output. Then use software or video streaming through etherent to feed them.

Comment: These monitors are spread throughout the office and will not be getting connected directly to the PC through the graphics card.  Looking more for a solution that will allow me to run ethernet to these monitors and push out video that way.